# Update multiple rows with different values in Laravel using eloquent and SnmpDriver migration

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-update

I want to update (every row) column `VALUE` in table `SNMP_DRIVER`, but I dont know the code to update.

This is table my database

[image: Table in my database]

This is code on my Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SnmpDriverModel extends Model
{
    protected $table ='SNMP_DRIVER';
    protected $fillable = [
        'CONFIG_ITEM',
        'VALUE'
    ];
}
```

This is my `view.blade.php` code

```
    <form id="update_snmp" name="update_snmp" action="snmp-driver/update" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        @foreach($snmp_driver_ver as $sdv)
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- <input id="CONFIG_ITEM1" name="CONFIG_ITEM1" type="hidden" value="Version" required="required"> -->
            <label for="snmp-ver" class="col-form-label">SNMP Version</label>
            <input id="snmp-ver" name="VALUE1" type="text" required="required" readonly value="{{$sdv->VALUE}}" class="col col-lg-5 form-control" placeholder="SNMPv2c">
        </div>
        @endforeach
        @foreach($snmp_driver_port as $sdp)
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- <input id="CONFIG_ITEM2" name="CONFIG_ITEM2" type="hidden" value="Port" required="required"> -->
            <label for="snmp-port" class="col-form-label">Port</label>
            <input id="snmp-port" name="VALUE2" type="text" value="{{$sdp->VALUE}}" required="required" class="col col-lg-5 form-control">
        </div>
        @endforeach
        @foreach($snmp_driver_username as $sdu)
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- <input id="CONFIG_ITEM3" name="CONFIG_ITEM3" type="hidden" value="Username" required="required">  -->
            <label for="snmp-uname" class="col-form-label">SNMPv2 Username</label>
            <input id="snmp-uname" name="VALUE3" type="text" value="{{$sdu->VALUE}}" required="required" class="col col-lg-5 form-control">
        </div>
        @endforeach
        <div class="form-group row text-right">
            <div class="col offset-sm-1 offset-lg-0">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-space btn-primary">Apply</button>
                <button class="btn btn-space btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

So, what is the code that can use to fill this controller to update?

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Do you want to update all rows? or specific row with specific `id`?

Comment: update all rows, but only column `VALUE` @EyadJaabo

Comment: You can do something like `SnmpDriverModel::where('VALUE', 1)->update('VALUE' => $request->value);`

Comment: you can make any condition you want.

Comment: yes, but my codes always failed to run @EyadJaabo

Comment: Update your question with SnmpDriver migration, please.

Comment: alright @EyadJaabo